# Ignore argument missing error in ellipsis function

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

The following piece of code produces  `Error: argument is missing, with no default` because of the trailing comma from the caller.

```
new_game <- function(...) {
  list(...)
}

game <- new_game(
  c(1,2,3),
  c(1,2),
  c(3),
  c(2),
  c(1), # the comma here is the culprit
)
```

Is it possible to circumvent this error by simply ignoring the last "argument"?

I wanted to design my function like this because, similar to how Rust has [trailing commas](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/trailing-commas-in-matches-structs-c/683) in match statements or structs, or how Go has [trailing commas](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/04/that-trailing-comma) in composite literals, it makes it easier to rearrange, add, remove lines and commit and pull changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is an odd beast because even though the syntax clearly allows trailing commas, it doesn’t just discard/ignore them, as other languages do. Instead, R pretends that a “missing” argument has been passed. As long as nothing touches the missing argument, that’s a-ok. We can even use this situation without dots:

```
f = function (a, b, c) a + b
```

Since `c` is never read, we don’t need to pass it:

```
f(1, 2)   # works
f(1, 2, ) # works, too
```

Not very useful, perhaps. But the following also works:

```
g = function (a, b, c) a + b + if (missing(c)) 0 else c
```

```
g(1, 2)    # 3
g(1, 2, )  # 3
g(1, 2, 3) # 6
```

… unfortunately this doesn’t help us directly to capture `...`.

Short of using a read-made solution (e.g. `rlang::list2`), the only real way to capture dots (allowing trailing commas) is to work on *unevaluated* arguments, and to manually evaluate them (we might instead be tempted to try `missing(...elt(...length()))`; alas R doesn’t accept that).

There are different ways of getting at the unevaluated dot arguments. The simplest way is to use `match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...`. Which leaves us with:

```
new_game = function (...) {
    args = match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
    nargs = length(args)
    if (identical(args[[nargs]], quote(expr = ))) nargs = nargs - 1L
    lapply(args[seq_len(nargs)], eval, envir = parent.frame())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a whole [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dots) on `...` where one is able to use `...length()` and `...elt(x)` to access specific parameters. I decided to put everything in a try-catch block - if an error is thrown, it's probably due to the missing argument at the end (note that `missing(...elt(...length()))` does not work).

```
game <- function(...) {
  tryCatch(
    list(...),
    error = function(e) lapply(1:(...length()-1), function(x) ...elt(x))
  )
}
```

Alternatively [`rlang`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/dyn-dots.html) offers `list2` specifically for this usecase.

```
game <- function(...) {
  rlang::list2(...)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `tryCatch` solution masks other errors, so I would (strongly) recommend against it. You *can* do this manually (without `rlang::list2`) but it involves iterating over the unevaluated function arguments (e.g. via `function (...) match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...`), and manually evaluating them.

Comment: Shouldn't errors still be thrown when calling `lapply` in the error function? (of course ignoring the last argument still might not be ideal in that case)

Comment: Right, it fails if the error is in the last argument (e.g. `game(1, stop('foo'))`). If the error is somewhere else it does stop, but it also creates and additional (and confusing, to the user) error message (`game(1, stop('foo'), 2)`). Certainly not the end of the world, of course.